# Does Rally Excel Plug-in work with SSO?

Tags: rally

My organization uses SSO for Rally authentication. With that said, can i configure SSO url with SSO id/pwd to use the Excel Plug-in from Excel? or should my Rally id be added in the Exception list, in order for me to use the Excel Plug-in, so that i use the Rally public url with rally user id/pwd for Excel Plug-in configuration. Any idea on this configuration?

Answer (score 1):

At this point white listing your Rally username is necessary. Your Rally id has to be added to the exception list since the plugin does not support SSO yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special SSO enabled Rally-Excel plugin, although it is currently in beta version. Ask your organization or Rally contact for this plugin. Since the plugin that is available online has SSO disabled. I faced a similar situation and then my manager provided me the plugin that had SSO enabled. So I am pretty sure you can get that one.

Answer (score 0):

We have SSO enabled via a desktop link for Rally as well.  Whenever I enter Rally via the link it works fine.

That said the SSO set up was done via IE and I prefer Chrome, when I open Rally via Chrome, (Just enter rally1.rallydev.com it takes me to to the Rally log-in page.  As long as you know your credentials (or can get an admin to have the system email you to reset them) you can log-in manually OR via SSO.